# Compilation: How to get rid of MainEvaluate[Hold[myFunction][arg1, arg2, arg3]]

Tags: compile, evaluation, inline

I am trying the following code:

```
riskFactor = 0.815; (* Used to ammend liquidation price*)
bitmexTakerFee = 0.00075; (* 0.075% , see \
https://www.bitmex.com/app/fees*)

bitmexMarginC = Compile[{{quantity, _Real}, {leverage, _Real}},
   (1/leverage)  quantity + 2 bitmexTakerFee ,

   Parallelization -> True, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
   CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True, 
     "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True, 
     "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];



bitmexComputeLiqC = 
  Compile[{{entry, _Real}, {target, _Real}, {leverage, _Real}}, 
   entry + If[target > entry, -1, 1] riskFactor* entry/leverage,

   Parallelization -> True, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
   CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True, 
     "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True, 
     "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];



bitmexProfitC = 
  Compile[{{quantity, _Real}, {entry, _Real}, {exit, _Real} , \
{leverage, _Real}, {direction, _Real}},
   Sign@direction 100 (entry/exit) (exit/entry - 1)  leverage,

   Parallelization -> True, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
   CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True, 
     "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True, 
     "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];



pctToAbsPriceC = 
  Compile[{{sEntry, _Real}, {sTarget, _Real}, {x, _Real}},
   ((sTarget - sEntry) x/100 + sEntry),

   Parallelization -> True, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
   CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True, 
     "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True, 
     "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];



absPriceToPctC = 
  Compile[{{sEntry, _Real}, {sTarget, _Real}, {x, _Real}},
    100 (x - sEntry)/(sTarget - sEntry) ,

   Parallelization -> True, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
   CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True, 
     "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True, 
     "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];



tradeResultCC = 
  Compile[{{data, _Real, 
     1}, {sEntry, _Real}, {sTarget, _Real}, {pctEntry, _Real}, \
{pctTarget, _Real}, {pctStop, _Real}, {leverage, _Real}},
   Module[
    {
     entryWindowEndTick = Quotient[Length@ data, 4],
     dir = sTarget - sEntry,
     pctLiq = 0.0,
     entryTick = -100,
     targetTick = Length@ data*100,
     stopTick = Length@ data*100,
     liqTick = Length@ data*100,
     liqPrice = 0,
     firstTick = -100,
     result = 0,
     profit = 0.0,
     n = 1,
     min = -1
     },
    pctLiq = 
     absPriceToPctC[sEntry, sTarget, 
      bitmexComputeLiqC[pctToAbsPriceC[sEntry, sTarget, pctEntry], 
       pctToAbsPriceC[sEntry, sTarget, pctTarget], leverage]];
    While[
     Sign[First@data - pctEntry] == Sign[data[[n]] - pctEntry] && 
      n < entryWindowEndTick, n++];
    If[n == entryWindowEndTick, entryTick = -100, entryTick = n];
    If[entryTick == -100, profit = 0, (* Entry didnt reached, 
     no trade, so 0 benefit *)
     n = entryTick;
     While[
      Not[data[[n]] >= pctTarget || data[[n]] <= pctStop || 
         data[[n]] <= pctLiq] && n < Length@data, n++];
     If[n >= Length@data, targetTick = Length@data,
      If [data[[n]] >= pctTarget, targetTick = n];
      If [data[[n]] <= pctStop , stopTick = n];
      If [data[[n]] <= pctLiq , liqTick = n]
      ];
     (*Print["n = ",n];
     Print["targetTick = ",targetTick];
     Print["stopTick = ",stopTick];
     Print["liqTick = ",liqTick];*)
     min = Min[targetTick, stopTick, liqTick];
     profit = Which[
       min == targetTick,
       bitmexProfitC[leverage, 
        pctToAbsPriceC[sEntry, sTarget, pctEntry], 
        pctToAbsPriceC[sEntry, sTarget, data[[targetTick]]], leverage,
         dir],
       min == stopTick,
       (*Print["stop"];*)
       bitmexProfitC[leverage, 
        pctToAbsPriceC[sEntry, sTarget, pctEntry], 
        pctToAbsPriceC[sEntry, sTarget, data[[stopTick]]], leverage, 
        dir],
        min == liqTick,
       (*Print["liquidation"];*)
       -101,
       True,
       -9999999999 (*Cannot happen, needed for Which to compile *)
       ];
     ];
    profit
    ],


   Parallelization -> True, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
   CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True, 
     "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True, 
     "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}
   ];
```

I've been working to make tradeResultCC compile to plain C code. However, I still get some MainEvaluate calls when I inspect it:

```
<< CompiledFunctionTools`
CompilePrint@tradeResultCC
(...)
139 R10 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[pctToAbsPriceC][ R0, R1, R2]]
(...)
167 R6 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[pctToAbsPriceC][ R0, R1, R2]]
```

I don't understand why those MainEvaluate calls are there,  and how is that not inlined.

I am using Mathematica 11.2

Comment: `bitmexMarginC` cannot avoid MainEvaluate because `bitmexTakerFee` is undefined, and `bitmexComputeLiqC`cannot avoid it because `riskFactor` is undefined.  If you fix those, it should work.

Comment: @QuantumDot sorry, those are defined but I forgot to copy them. I have fixed the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because you are using *Mathematica* 11.2 which does not faithfully inline the definitions of the CompiledFunctions.  Mathematica 12 has no problems with your code.

As a workaround, you can manually inline the definitions by *injecting* the relevant code with the help of `With`.  I have taken the liberty of making your code work in version 11.2.

```
riskFactor = 0.815; (*Used to ammend liquidation price*)
bitmexTakerFee = 
  0.00075; (*0.075%,see https://www.bitmex.com/app/fees*)

bitmexMarginC = With[{bitmexTakerFee = bitmexTakerFee},
   Function[{quantity, leverage},
    (1/leverage) quantity + 2 bitmexTakerFee]
   ];

bitmexComputeLiqC = With[{riskFactor = riskFactor},
   Function[{entry, target, leverage},
    entry + If[target > entry, -1, 1] riskFactor*entry/leverage
    ]
   ];

bitmexProfitC = Function[{quantity, entry, exit, leverage, direction},
   Sign@direction 100 (entry/exit) (exit/entry - 1) leverage
   ];

pctToAbsPriceC = Function[{sEntry, sTarget, x},
   ((sTarget - sEntry) x/100 + sEntry)
   ];

absPriceToPctC = Function[{sEntry, sTarget, x},
   100 (x - sEntry)/(sTarget - sEntry)
   ];

tradeResultCC = With[
   {bitmexMarginC = bitmexMarginC, 
    bitmexComputeLiqC = bitmexComputeLiqC, 
    bitmexProfitC = bitmexProfitC, pctToAbsPriceC = pctToAbsPriceC, 
    absPriceToPctC = absPriceToPctC},
   Compile[
    {{data, _Real, 
      1}, {sEntry, _Real}, {sTarget, _Real}, {pctEntry, _Real}, \
{pctTarget, _Real}, {pctStop, _Real}, {leverage, _Real}},

    Module[
     {entryWindowEndTick = Quotient[Length@data, 4],
      dir = sTarget - sEntry,
      pctLiq = 0.0,
      entryTick = -100,
      targetTick = Length@data*100,
      stopTick = Length@data*100,
      liqTick = Length@data*100,
      liqPrice = 0,
      firstTick = -100,
      result = 0,
      profit = 0.0,
      n = 1,
      min = -1
      },

     pctLiq = 
      absPriceToPctC[sEntry, sTarget, 
       bitmexComputeLiqC[pctToAbsPriceC[sEntry, sTarget, pctEntry], 
        pctToAbsPriceC[sEntry, sTarget, pctTarget], leverage]];
     While[
      Sign[First@data - pctEntry] == Sign[data[[n]] - pctEntry] && 
       n < entryWindowEndTick, n++];
     If[n == entryWindowEndTick, entryTick = -100, entryTick = n];
     If[entryTick == -100, profit = 0,(*Entry didnt reached,no trade,
      so 0 benefit*)
      n = entryTick;
      While[
       Not[data[[n]] >= pctTarget || data[[n]] <= pctStop || 
          data[[n]] <= pctLiq] && n < Length@data, n++];
      If[n >= Length@data,
       targetTick = Length@data,
       If[data[[n]] >= pctTarget, targetTick = n];
       If[data[[n]] <= pctStop, stopTick = n];
       If[data[[n]] <= pctLiq, liqTick = n]];

      (*Print["n = ",n];
      Print["targetTick = ",targetTick];
      Print["stopTick = ",stopTick];
      Print["liqTick = ",liqTick];*)

      min = Min[targetTick, stopTick, liqTick];
      profit = Which[
        min == targetTick,
        bitmexProfitC[leverage, 
         pctToAbsPriceC[sEntry, sTarget, pctEntry], 
         pctToAbsPriceC[sEntry, sTarget, data[[targetTick]]], 
         leverage, dir],

        min == stopTick,
        (*Print["stop"];*)
        bitmexProfitC[leverage, 
         pctToAbsPriceC[sEntry, sTarget, pctEntry], 
         pctToAbsPriceC[sEntry, sTarget, data[[stopTick]]], leverage, 
         dir],

        min == liqTick,
        (*Print["liquidation"];*)
        -101,

        True,
        -9999999999 (*Cannot happen,needed for Which to compile*)];];
     profit],

    Parallelization -> True, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
    CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
    CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True, 
      "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True, 
      "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}]
   ];
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I've submited an edit to your answer fixing the spacing.